# Importing XML files into excel with numbers of over 15 digits

Tags: excel, xml, digits

I have an xml file which I am trying to import into excel but the most important column being imported has 18 digits and excel only allows up to 15 digits.

I have tried setting the column to text after importing but the last 3 digits are just 000. i can't work with these numbers as every digit is important as i'm dealing with barcodes.

I'm trying to think of a way I can preset the column to be text so when I'm importing it will be text immediately. Any ideas or suggestions on what I could do?

thanks.

Comment: You can prefix the number with a character. "SN" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an XML doc like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<number>12345678901234567890</number>`

Create an XSD doc like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>`

You've defined an element with the name of "number" and a string data type. Now any element in your XML file that's in "number" tags will be string formatted.

In a workbook, go to the Developer tab, XML group, and click Source. This shows the XML task pane. Here you'll add the xsd file. Click `XML Maps` then `Add` and load your xsd file.

[image: add an xsd to a workbook]

Now your task pane will show your map - we only have one element, so it's pretty simple

[image: the xml task pane shows define element]

Next, drag the number element to a cell in your workbook. There won't be any data yet because we haven't imported the xml.

[image: drag an element to a cell]

Last, go back to Developer - XML and click Import. Import your xml file. Excel will map all the elements to the cells where you defined elements. Even Excel now recognizes that it's treating a number as test. But no truncation.

[image: Excel respects the xsd element data type]

Comment: I was hoping I could just create the schema file and refer to it from the XML file, but I couldn't get it to work. If you could do that, you could skip all the mapping nonsense and just have Excel use the schema. But like I said, it was beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution without having to create your own XSD Doc**

1. Import XML File via Developer Tools and let Excel automatically generate the Schema as you did before [XML Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FgbO.png)
2. Save your file as an XML Spreadsheet [Save as XML Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9g6D.png) and close it afterwards
3. Open this XML spreadsheet with an editor, e.g. Notepad / Notepad++ and search for "MapInfo" (should be towards the end of the file) [Search XML Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfDGt.png)
4. Change the "XSDType" of the field you want to change to "string" [Change XSD Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wamF0.png) and save
5. Open the changed XML Spreadsheet with Excel and save it as .xlsx [Save XML as XLSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go7WC.png)
6. Open your newly saved .XLSX and import your XML file again [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibSgY.png)

Answer (score 0):

How I did solved the problem

1. Open the file with the existing XML sheme
2. Run macros

   Sub save_XML_scheme()
   Dim fPath As String
   Dim s As String
   fPath = "C:\TEMP\sc1.xsd"
   s = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).Schemas(1).XML
   Open fPath For Output As #1
   Print #1, s
   Close #1
   MsgBox "XMLsheme file saved as C:\TEMP\sc1.xsd "
   End Sub
3. In file sc1.xsd for the field I need to make string type. I change parameter to "string" -
   in my case it was `type="xsd:string" name="SSCC"`
4. Open again the xml file and choose "Use the XML Source task pane" then press XMLMaps->Add -> then choose the added scheme ->OK
5. Then Developer-Import-choose XML file